# Does diesel support python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Interested in the diesel networking library (http://diesel.io). Will it run on python 3.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/jamwt/diesel/blob/master/diesel/protocols/websockets.py

This modules uses `xrange`, which was removed in Python 3. Apparently, Diesel doesn't support Python 3 out of box.

Comment: I worry it may not be in active development anymore either as it was primarily used at bump, which is no longer a service.

Comment: yikes. if gevent doesn't get their act together tulip is going to be the standard for big python server apps.

Answer (score 0):

It appears Diesel does not support Python 3.3 (or any 3.X version) at this point.

Source: https://github.com/jamwt/diesel/blob/master/setup.py

```
import select, sys, os
assert sys.version_info >= (2, 6), \
"Diesel requires python 2.6 (or greater 2.X release)"
```

Comment: (3, 0) >= (2, 6), this test means nothing.

Comment: This code is directly from their setup.py file and it explicitly says "2.X release" and not 3.X.

Comment: Yeah, except you'll never see it.

Comment: While true, that's irrelevant. There's obviously a reason that they specify 2.X and not 3.X, whether or not their test is a correct test is not the point of this question nor answer.

Comment: You're right, the developers likely didn't think about Python 3 at that moment. Yet the code might still "accidentally" work on Python 3 (though it seems not to be the case).